# Word for relating to class

Tags: single-word-requests

Classial? Classical? None of these are the answer. What am I supposed to say?

I want to say, "A [insert the right word here] divide," but cannot

Comment: What meaning of class are you referring to?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. In order for us to answer a question, it needs to be clear about what is being asked, and to demonstrate what efforts you've already made into researching the question. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] for further guidance. *Class* has several different meanings, and it is not clear which one you are interested in. The word you want is probably just *class*, as in *class distinction* or *class convergence*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are using "class" to refer to social status, you can, perhaps unexpectedly, just use **class** in your example sentence:

> A class divide.

In the Boston Globe, the article ["How the Travel Industry Exploits the Class Divide"](https://www.bostonglobe.com/lifestyle/travel/2017/09/28/how-travel-industry-exploits-class-divide/6ww1WiH98hccaLFgi3LepO/story.html) makes use of this term:

> The class divide is not unique to travel, Terrill said. “There’s a divide in every aspect of life,” she said. “If I go to the mall, there’s a Nieman Marcus and a Saks Fifth Avenue, and I don’t shop there. Instead I’m going to go to Macy’s and hope I can get some things on sale. So is there a divide? Yes. There’s a divide everywhere.”

---

If, on the other hand, you are referring to "class" in relation to school, then your example sentence would need to be rephrased:

> A class divided.
>   A division in the class.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are referring to class as in social or economic class, the correct word is simply "class". In English we often use the phrase "a class divide".